# How to make this specific sql query using Flask MySQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query and fetch the last row of my database using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'removed'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="removed",
    password="removed",
    hostname="removed",
    databasename="removed",
)   #used to use sqlite here so potential for errors...
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299 #do i need this line and below line???
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class temperaturelog(db.Model):
    TemperatureID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Temperature = db.Column(db.Float(5))
    dTime = db.Column(db.DateTime) #check the actual data types here

    def __init__(self, TemperatureID, Temperature, dTime):
        self.TemperatureID = TemperatureID
        self.Temperature = Temperature
        self.dTime = dTime

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%r' % self.Temperature

def getTemperatureData():
    #need to convert this query into sqlalchemy queries "SELECT * FROM readings ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    #need to connect/use the right table below
    #data = jsonify(temperaturelog.query.order_by(temperaturelog.dTime.desc()).first())
    datalist = {}
    data = temperaturelog.query.order_by(temperaturelog.TemperatureID.desc()).first()
    data = data.Temperature
    datalist["temperature"] = data
    datalist["datetime"] = "12-12-12 23-23-23"
    datalist = json.dumps(datalist)
    return datalist
```

Here I connect to an online database (I am using pythonanywhere to host this all) and I need the last row of data in my database I believe the usual SQL command would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM readings ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
```

How ever when I use the below code to try and retrieve the dTime value for further processing it throws the error object 'float' does not have attributes .dTime , so thus my query is simply returning the temperature, how do I make the query return the whole last row so I can use the .Temperature and .dTime to access particular values?

```
data2 = data.dTime
datalist["datetime"] = data2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getTemperatureData()` you use the `data` variable to store the query result set first:

```
data = temperaturelog.query.order_by(temperaturelog.TemperatureID.desc()).first()
```

In the next line you overwrite `data` with the temperature (which is probably a float):

```
data = data.Temperature
```

So, next time you try to use `data`, it contains a float and not the result set.
Rename the variable in the second line, for example, to `data_temperature`.